# Does the duration of the head-hair growth phase differ between men and women?

Tags: human-biology, hair, sexual-dimorphism

I found [one website](https://www.renefurterer.com/en-ca/tips/scalp/the-physiology-of-the-scalp/the-life-cycle-of-hair) which claims the following

> The growth phase of the hair is called the anagen phase. It lasts
> about 3 years in men and 5 years in women.

[Another website](https://crlab.com/en_en/scientific-area/hair-and-scalp/life-cycle-of-hair/) makes a very similar claim.

The problem is I can't find any journal article which supports the idea. Is it true that the anagen phase lasts longer in women than in men? And is there published research to prove it?

Comment: Both these articles are from companies that sell cosmetic products. If their "research departments" have any data to support any scientific statements they make they are unlikely to be interested in publishing it. It sounds uncontroversial and may be old observations or old wives' tales nobody has cared enough about to investigate. Not where modern biology is, for sure, but you never know whether your bounty will bring something out of the woodwork.